# MySql performance find all users that are within 1 km

Tags: mysql, sql, complexity-theory, spatial, spatial-index

I have mysql table, need to find all users that are within 1 km of each other
Table:

```
Geo
----------
id(int)
location(geometry)  with spatial index
username(string)
```

could be solved:

1. iterate by users i ... n
2. for each select all users within specific polygon, using index
3. send msg each other

so complexity would be ~O(n) or more (depends on index), any other solutions with better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is 2D, and you know your radius, you can build a grid index for your data. Then each cell will send messages to each neighboring cell only.

Computing the cell assignment is O(n). So this should bring this task down to `n * O(m * m)`, when `m` is your maximum cell occupancy.

Note that it's hard to guarantee anything here. If all your objects are within a radius of 1 km, no index will help you much. Everybody has to send to everybody else, os it will be quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql uses [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) to for [spatial indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimizing-spatial-analysis.html) so as long as your index fits in memory you should have better than O(n) performance.

Comment: OP is asking to do this for all users, so if the index gives something like `O(ln(n))` for one lookup, then its going to be `O(n.ln(n))` to do it for all users?